# Do we allow audio artifacts in game-identification questions?

Tags: support

[Where does Freak Fortress 2's The Tank theme (titled metalfox.mp3) come from?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/207601/looking-for-the-game-this-song-is-from?noredirect=1#comment280797_207601)

I posted the question above to which a user immediately cast a close vote and a downvote, citing that an audio artifact wasn't representative enough of a game and thus my question should have been closed.

Was I in the wrong here? I specifically recalling that ITG questions could be asked should the OP provide an audio or visual artifact. But so far I have 2 close votes citing the question I asked as off-topic. Is it really?

It looks like in the entirety of site's history, we have had only [1 previous audio-solely ITG question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/178128/from-what-game-does-the-following-music-come-from/178144#178144), which was answered by murgatroid99. That question was not closed and did not receive any downvotes.

Comment: I'd already asked such a question — http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/17722/where-does-the-illusion-world-song-from-chocobo-racing-come-from — but self-deleted it when the ITG ban was a blanket one and didn't allow for the "actual artifact" exception. Incidentally I believe a song is plenty concrete material to work with.

Comment: I know the argument just happened, but I feel that naming specific names is almost always less than constructive. The fact that there are close votes and downvotes on that question are sufficient reason for asking this one.

Comment: Also, as a data point, [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/178128/from-what-game-does-the-following-music-come-from) also asks about identifying a game from a song, and seemed to be less controversial.

Comment: My position for ITG exceptions is that it must come from the game itself.  And hearing something, and having someone say they *think* it comes from a game does not match the criteria we established in the first place.  It is, in fact, the entire reason we threw a blanket ban on ITG in the first place; memory is inherently faulty.

Comment: Incidentally, my argument isn't that the artifact isn't sufficient; it's the impetus that someone said it was from a game that threw it over the line. Does that mean I can listen to a random thing from wherever, think it's from a game, and then ask a question about it?

Comment: @Frank I think the fundamental problem with ITG questions was that the **correctness of the answer** depended on the memory of the asker. A/V artifact questions avoid that because any user can verify that the artifact is associated with the game by inspection. This is true whether or not the artifact actually comes from a game; if it does not, there will simply be no correct answer.

Comment: I can see where Frank's coming from, the OP saying "I think it's from a game" implies that we're relying on the askers memory. However, as they have provided a specific artifact, we can perform searches (exhaustive or otherwise) which will either turn up something, or won't. *"No, it's not from a(nother) game"* would also have sufficed as an answer should it have been the case.

Answer (score 7):

Given the discussion and the votes on this question it seems reasonable to conclude this: the community consensus says those questions are on-topic. The rationale is that, unlike what happens with banned "open-ended" ITG questions, audio- and music-based game identification questions have falsifiable answers. This trait is shared with other game-id questions we already do allow.